# Indicative Past vs Present with Write

Tags: verbs, tenses, indicative

[Write tenses and formations](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/English/write.html)

I always get told off for saying `I wrote an email` and told I should say `I have written an email`. Why? When should you use these different tenses. Or point me towards a good cheat sheet.

Comment: related [Simple Past vs. Present Perfect: “was” vs. “has been”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73143/simple-past-vs-present-perfect-was-vs-has-been) Which has been closed as a duplicate, but I think the answers there will be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are entirely correct to say you wrote an email. It tells me that on one specific occasion you wrote an email. If you say you have written an email I might understand the same but could also understand that on some unspecified occasion you wrote an email.

Compare "I went to London. I wrote an email" and "I went to London. I have written an email". The first associates the writing with your being in London. The second tells us nothing about where you wrote your email.